# Getting error, "CreateProcess error=206, The filename or extension is too long", when trying to add "spring-boot-starter-data-cassandra" v2.7.18

Tags: spring-boot, cassandra

**Environment** : Windows/jdk11

I have a project which will compile fine, however when I add

```
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-cassandra</artifactId>
      <version>2.7.18</version>
    </dependency>
```

All of the sudden I get

> CreateProcess error=206, The filename or extension is too long

when I try to run `spring-boot:run`

Does anyone know what would cause this?

I am using Java 11

Answer (score 1):

The error "CreateProcess error=206, The filename or extension is too long" on Windows typically occurs due to exceeding the maximum path length limit. This can happen when Maven builds the classpath with long dependencies. To resolve:

Shorten directory paths or use shorter names.
Enable Win32 long paths.
Exclude unnecessary dependencies.
Update Maven or consider migrating to Gradle.

Comment: unfortunately this didn't help in my case. I moved the folder to the c: with the same issue and the file name is under 20 or so chars (including the names of subfolders)